# Does Std have a Default Properties Checker

Tags: c++, std, template-meta-programming, requires-clause

When I write a template class that I could change based on certain template special cases, then there are sometimes situations where even despite good encapsulation I find myself at debate between actually implementing a full template class specialization or just adding one or two attributes that in half of the cases would be unutilized.

Now, with a meta-programming property check I hope to find a good in-betweener.

The idea is (something) like:

```cpp
template<Property ...myProperties>
struct PropertyList{
    template<PropertyArgs ...args>
    static constexpr bool is_satisfied = /*...*/;
};
```

And the idea is that this returns `true` if each property in arg is satisfied by at least one property of myProperties.

So for example if
`myProperties={ Color is red , Color is green , Material is iron }`
and
`args={ Color is red , Material is iron }`
then `is_satisfied = true`.

I have implemented this now myself ( I use Property<typename T, T t>{ is_satisfied = (S!=T) or (s==t); }; where T is typically an enum ) but I would be surprised if the standard just hasn't something for exactly this case.

Let me know what you use :)

PS: I use a lot of requirements (concepts) but I cannot make them suitable for those cases I have in mind with the properties such as, e.g., default assignments of attributes or constexpr branches / template arguments. (I see how this is the other way round to concepts: those determine branches on the function call receiver, whereas my properties could be used on the issuer side.)

Comment: "Does Std have a Default Properties Checker" - No, not as you define it, not as far as I know.

Comment: Aren't you trying to reinvent type traits and CRTP here?